# Cannot read from serial USB device

Tags: usb, python, serial-port

I have a lab equipment ([CAEN DT1470ET](https://www.caen.it/products/dt1470et/)) connected via USB to a Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have installed the graphical interface software from the manufacturer and it connects properly with the instrument. However, when I try to do it with Python, I can't.

This is my code:

```
import serial
import time

CAEN = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttyACM0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = 1,
    bytesize = 8,
    xonxoff = True,
    timeout = 1,
)
command = 'BD:0,CMD:MON,PAR:BDFREL\r\n'.encode('ASCII')
print(f'Sending: {command}')
CAEN.write(command)
time.sleep(1)
print(f'Reading...')
print(CAEN.read(111))
```

The problem is in the line `CAEN.read`. It always goes to the timeout so it always prints `b''` (i.e. empty answer), and if the `timeout=1` line is removed it stays there indefinitely.

If I run `udevadm info -r -q all /dev/ttyACM0` I get:

```
$ udevadm info -r -q all /dev/ttyACM0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
N: ttyACM0
L: 0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
S: serial/by-id/usb-CAEN_SPA_NIM_Desktop_HV_Power_Supply-if00
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=17958516201
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=21e1
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0003
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Serial bus controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=USB controller
E: ID_PCI_INTERFACE_FROM_DATABASE=XHCI
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporation
E: ID_VENDOR=CAEN_SPA
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=CAEN\x20SPA
E: ID_MODEL=NIM_Desktop_HV_Power_Supply
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=NIM\x2fDesktop\x20HV\x20Power\x20Supply
E: ID_REVISION=0100
E: ID_SERIAL=CAEN_SPA_NIM_Desktop_HV_Power_Supply
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Communications
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_1_1_0
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-CAEN_SPA_NIM_Desktop_HV_Power_Supply-if00
E: TAGS=:systemd:
```

I have already set the permissions to the serial port with `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't ever change access rights in /dev. It is a virtual filesystem and your changes will be reset at next reboot. The right solution is to add your user to the right group. Use `ls -l /dev/ttyACM0` to see what group is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my problem is not related to the permission to read/write but with something else. I never receive any answer from the device, and I don't know if this is a Linux problem or a device problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the end all the problem was that I was missing a `$` character in the beginning of each command, so the command to send would be

```
command = '$BD:0,CMD:MON,PAR:BDFREL\r\n'.encode('ASCII')
```

I discarded syntax errors because in that case I was expecting some answer from the device saying that there is an error in the command, but it seems that for this mistake the answer is just silence and this got me confused. (Also I was unaware of the missing `$`.)